# Can you add more loop subdivides later?

Tags: edit-mode

If you create an object, then subdivide it (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>r</kbd>), how can you later add more loop subdivides?

For example, if I try and add more loop cuts, the are confined to only a portion of the cube.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

One thing you can do is this:

1. Switch to edge select mode (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)
2. Select an edge ring (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>)
3. Multi select edge loops (Fastest to access via the <kbd>Space</kbd> menu)
4. Subdivide

Example:

[image]

However this only lets you double the number of existing loops.

Without deleting loops/other manual tricks, I don't think there is currently a way of getting a precise number of evenly distributed loops, especially on more complex objects.

See [Is there any way to edit parameters for an object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7850/599)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a better way of doing it, but you could try selecting the edges from the original loop cut and using limited dissolve (press x, click limited dissolve) and re-doing the loop cut after.  might need to use a different dissolve option.  Again, just a quick thought...there may be a better way