# How to make Sapling addon settings reappear?

Tags: interface, add-on, sapling-addon

The menu for settings disappears when I click on another menu. How do I make it visual again?

When modeling trees with the Sapling add-on, if I click *Undo* the settings disappear for the Sapling add-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard behavior. You can not edit any settings after editing, moving, deselecting, etc. anything in the scene without the editing menu being removed.

[**More information**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7851/6204)

Comment: well cool and all but say we ctrl-Z, why is it still not showing up then????