# How to change subdivisions after adding a grid

Tags: modeling

I'm following this [tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/An_aMAZEing_game_engine_tutorial), when I use Add > Mesh > grid and then scale it, I get a grid with 9x9 squares:

[image: 9x9 grid]

To make the maze, I want the grid to have more squares (15x15 for e.g) however, no mater how big I scale it it remains 9x9 squares.

Is there a way to control the number of squares this grid has?

Comment: Subdivide? (*W > Subdivide*)

Comment: I didn't even knew that grid object, thx!

Comment: It's only possible to change a primitive's attributes *immediately* after adding it. If you perform any action, it's set in stone. You also can't Ctrl-Z. All you can do after creating it is add a modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immediately after adding the grid (See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created/7851#7851) for details as to why it has to be immediate) you can access various options at the bottom of the 3D toolbar (where it says *Toggle Editmode* in your screenshot) such as the x and y subdivisions:

[image]

You can also access these options (again, immediately after adding the grid) by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.

So you should:

1. Add the grid.
2. Increase x and y subdivisions as desired.
3. *Then* scale the grid up as much as you want.

Comment: thanks it works, but it seems that the `F6` thing doesn't work(using blender 2.73)

Comment: @Mhmd It works for me. If you're using a laptop you might need to press another key for f-keys to work.