# Landscape tool options

Tags: interface, add-on

When I insert *Mesh > Landscape*, the landscape appears along with its specific toolbar on the left.  If I save the landscape, then reopen it, the landscape toolbar does not appear.  How do I make it appear?

Comment: See if this related question can halp you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is to add landscape once again if something went wrong and Ant Landscape toolset dissapeared. This can be done without reopening though.