# Landscape tool isn't visible in the transform menu

Tags: transforms, add-on

Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOJ9F-YBfhY), I am trying to create a landscape.

The video shows settings on the right-hand toolbar to modify the landscape, which I can't see on my version of Blender (2.75):

[image]

Where are the Landscape tools?

Comment: Further on in the video, the user explains that the tools disappear after you move the object along. Maybe I should delete or answer this question.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Comment: Any transformation after the object has been created will make that menu dissappear. There is no way to get back to it other than creating the object again.

Comment: can you make this an answer to be accepted and upvoted

Comment: I can't, the question is closed as a duplicate. Please up-vote the answer on the linked post :)