# How to modify gears add-on in Blender

Tags: modifiers, add-on

I'm very new to Blender and have a question that I hope someone can help me with. I am interested in using this [gears addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Gear).
I have installed the add-on into my version of Blender 2.76b (running on Ubuntu 14.04) from the py script but whatever I try and read I cannot find where to edit the gears (adjust radius, number of teeth etc...).

I'm very confused and hope someone can shine a light on my problem.
Many thanks,

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created ? Did you try using Last operator menu ?

Comment: To elaborate on @MrZak's comment... press T in the 3D view to enable the left-hand toolbar, and look at the bottom.  You may have to click the little "+" icon at the bottom to make it visible.

Comment: You should always try to look for the add-on wiki pages like this one http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Gear. Usually it's well documented.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but I have looked at the wiki page you mention and I simply cannot see anywhere the interface for editing the gears that it mentions. I think it must be missing. If I use the last operator menu and select gear, I still cannot see any edit tools in the tool bar (although there is a title 'gear' that appears but below is all empty.

Comment: If the operator properties are not visible at the bottom of your toolshelf region then there will be a little `+` at the bottom that will bring it back. You can also press `F6` to show the operator properties in a floating panel.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I have followed the closely but I am convinced something is not right with my install of the add-on. I'll report back here if I make any progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can find details in Custom properties section of related objects properties menu on the right hand side of the screen.