# How to get the menu with Add Gear options back?

Tags: add-on

I'm new to Blender and I've figured out how to make a gear but I have a question!

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh* > *Gears* > *Gear* will add a new default gear to the build area and will bring up an Add Gear menu in the *Toolshelf* on the left where you can change all aspects of the gear.

But once the gear's object was moved / the interaction mode was changed / any other action was done, the Add Gear menu on the left disappears.
How do I get this menu back?

Comment: There is no way to get it back once you've created an object and modified it somehow you can't go back to the original creation settings.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Comment: I can´t add an answer so I´m doing caps to bring attention: YOU CAN BRING IT BACK, at least in Blender  2.8, TRY HITTING F9 KEY.

Answer (score 2):

This menu is called the operator panel and it only pops up when you first create the object. If you make any changes to the object it will disappear forever.

If you didn't perform any action, hit <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring back the panel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply HowToBlend 
So how do you edit he gear once you've got it in place is there a properties sheet somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: @3DMan You have to edit make your changes first then move it - I know, an awkward mechanic but you do get used to it.

Comment: Think of it backwards: move the 3D cursor to where you need the object to be created. Create the gear in place, then you'll have access to the create parameters. Once you make any change to the gear, those parameters cannot be accessed again, and you'll have to edit the geometry of your object using tools in edit mode.