# Can't find landscape editor options?

Tags: objects, interface

I'm following as tutorial and once I inserted a Landscape object a whole lot of settings for the landscape came up on the left side of my screen.

I've somehow lost these setting and I can't find it. I may of accidentally pressed a button or something.

Comment: If you have modified the mesh, gone into edit mode, etc. then the operator panel will not be available for this action. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created