# How to increase number of turns when needed later in blender

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

When I work with the object the I "screwed" using blender then I see the turns property as I highlighted with yellow color in the image, but if I want to increase the number of turns after the work is completed then how can I see the turns property again.

I don't see it event I select the complete object by pressing 'A' please suggest if this option is available or not. If not then how can I do that? Is there any alternative solution to increase or decrease turns?

Comment: Use the screw modifier instead of doing it with the operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to edit parameters for an object after it is created?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)