# How do I scale a Torus's minor radius?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms

I have created a Torus and I've already been working a lot on it. But now I realized that its minor radius is too big and I need a way to scale it down after it has been created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to edit parameters for an object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)

Comment: This is why you should strive to use non destructive workflows and modifier based approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest a combination of scaling with <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> (Shrink/Fatten) and regular scaling with  <kbd>S</kbd>. Both in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: I like being an amateur newbie because you're still happy with the simple tricks :)