# taking a manuel bastoni character to another file

Tags: add-on, manuel-bastioni-lab

I wanted to test creating a character in another file, and now that I am satisfied with the character I wanted to move it to the original file, I used manuel bastioni lab for character creation but either copying the object or appending the object fails to copy all the data related with the character i.e. bastioni lab doesn't show the side pane of options and no posing rigs or anything with the appended character. It appends the object like it was poly modelled. What is the correct way to transfer a character from one file to another which was created with manuel bastioni?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos , Unlike the post you have posted to, manuel bastoni  editing options are consistent, even if you sculpt, edit, scale your model, you still have the editing options.... So....

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos , the post you're pointing to is addressing a different question