# How can I access "Object Parameters Tool" again after it's disappeared?

Tags: objects

Once I finish playing around the parameters, as I click aside, "The Object Parameters Tool" (I don't know how exactly it's called) disappear, and I can't find it anywhere to access it again. Please refer to the attached picture to see what tool I'm talking about. I'm new to Blender and I use Blender 2.80 Beta. Please help!

[image: How]s://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDKHa.jpg

Comment: Once you begin to move or edit your object you can't have access to the parameters anymore

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! It's upsetting though :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to edit parameters for an object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)