# Is it possible to add key frames to initial shape setting?

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, add-on, keyframes

when you first create a shape it asked you what you want to input for creating different variation of a shape, but one you click away those setting are gone forever. Is it possible to insert key frames into those initial settings?

Answer (score 0):

Not as keyframes, but you can create presets when you add a shape, by pressing the **+** sign right next to the operator presets.

[image]

By creating a preset you can recall custom settings.

Note that once you modify an object in any way there is no way to go back and re-edit the parameters of the created object.

Read: [Is there any way to edit parameters for an object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)

If you want to create an animation by modifying the shape look into using shapekeys

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/index.html