# Reducing the number of vertices

Tags: vertices

I am trying to reduce the number of vertices by the tutorial and when I press f6 like the video says nothing happens and the bar does not appear?
[CGC Classic: Female Character Modeling Pt. 2 - Major Face Loops (Blender 2.6)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oa9ZRyBFcCg) , in this tutorial at 17:50minutes, a guy created a circle mesh and then by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> he decreased the number of vertices, however in my case <kbd>F6</kbd> does not show anything at all.

Comment: Without more information it is really hard to tell what's going on in your project. What could be is Global Undo disabled in user prefs (open them and find it on Editing tab); you didn't execute any operator first (F6 is based on redoing last operation with different settings) or you use 2.8 and F6 doesn't open that menu there (not sure about recet builds). You can edit your question and include more information like screenshots, what tutorial you use etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oa9ZRyBFcCg That is the tutorial I used, (17:50 minutes) The guy was doing a circle mesh and then he pressed F6 to reduce the number of vertices. So that is  what I was doing basically. But when I pressed it nothing appeared and I tried to do it in other way but did not find anything.

Comment: Could be that your keyboard's F6 key is mapped to something else by default (for example, volume control). Make sure you are pressing the function key at the same time if the key is not dedicated.

Comment: If you're in 2.7 and F6 doesn't work it means you've moved your primitive object and you can't have access to its basic settings anymore. Plus you need to know that these parameters are displayed on the bottom of the Tools panel on the left of the 3D view. If you are in 2.8 it looks like F6 doesn't work yet, the parameters are in the box on the bottom of the 3D view.

Comment: I am in 2.79 and I tried a lot of things, none of them work so I do not know what to do.

Comment: "none of them work" won't describe what exactly didn't work and at what step you need help. Make a screenshot and edit the post with the image (see [how to upload image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)), while making it include whole 3d viewport window with Toolshelf opened. Include information about Global Undo state in user prefs. Do note - last operator panel is available only after executing operation, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created.

Answer (score 0):

instead readd you circle and then go the left panel (press  <kbd>T</kbd>  button) and then you can decrease the number of vertices of your circle

[image]
[image]