# How to make a hollow cube object?

Tags: python

How to make a hollow cube object by Python?

```
edges = []
verts = [(1.0, 1, 0), (1.0, -1.0, 0), (-1, -1, 0), (-1, 1, 0),(2.0, 2, 0), (2.0, -2.0, 0), (-2, -2, 0), (-2, 2, 0)]
faces = [(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7)] 

mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new("cube_mesh_data")
mesh_data.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
mesh_data.update()
hsname='hollowobj'
hsobj = bpy.data.objects.new(hsname, mesh_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(hsobj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = hsobj
hsobj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLIDIFY')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].thickness = 2
```

But it did not work!

Comment: Hello, could you add a diagram or example of what you're trying to construct ?

Comment: If Tlousky's answer is not what you're after, then perhaps you just want to create two cubes - the inner cube would be the inner surface - of course you would have to flip the normals of the inner cube.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the bmesh create_cone operator to generate a hollowed out tube (essentially a 4 sided cylinder).

[image]

```
import bpy, bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_cone(
    bm, cap_ends=False, cap_tris=False, 
    segments=4, diameter1=1, diameter2=1, depth=2
)

name = 'Hollow Cube'
m = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)

C = bpy.context
S = bpy.context.scene

bm.to_mesh(m)

o = bpy.data.objects.new(name, m)
S.collection.objects.link(o)
```

You can later add a solidify modifier like you did (or by using the more efficient low-level `object.modifiers.new` method.

Answer (score 4):

**Reverse Engineer it.**

In answers to

[How to draw a circle hole by bmesh on the plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183939/how-to-draw-a-circle-hole-by-bmesh-on-the-plane)

and

and [Create Circle with Inner Radius](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146083/create-circle-with-inner-radius) (*Similarly to @Tlouskey mentions adding a cone, but whereas he is using solidify thickness for wall thickness,  cone with  `depth=0` and hence solidify thickness as height if you will*

demonstrate other methods to make a hole in a mesh object.

another would be add plane, inset face, then delete face.

[image]
*Reminder start with cursor in sensible position, anyway set inset to 1*

which could be coded, however and  having just done that, will use  [How do I Create a script for geometry I create?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65129/how-do-i-create-a-script-for-geometry-i-create) to *"reverse engineer it into a script"*

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

verts = ((-2.0, -2.0, 0.0),
         (2.0, -2.0, 0.0),
         (-2.0, 2.0, 0.0),
         (2.0, 2.0, 0.0),
         (-1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
         (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
         (1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
         (1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

faces = ((5, 4, 2, 0),
         (6, 5, 0, 1),
         (7, 6, 1, 3),
         (4, 7, 3, 2))

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Plane")
me.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Plane", me)
context.collection.objects.link(ob)
context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
```

edit to change "Plane" to suit, and as mentioned can add modifier by appending

```
sm = ob.modifiers.new("Solidify", 'SOLIDIFY')
sm.thickness = 2
```

to script.

Note.

To make the cube hollow by  giving it "wall thickness", can add the modifier directly to the default cube.

A sphere is used via boolean difference modifier for cutaway.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked very well!