# Mesh -> Math Function: Edit Dialog

Tags: mesh, mathematics

How do I pull up the Edit Dialog after it closes?  I have enabled Math Functions and it works fine; however, after I initially enter my settings in the dialog ("Add Z Function Surface"), the dialog disappears.  How can I pull up the dialog to change my settings?

I am using Blender 2.90.1, Windows 10.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit Parameters for an Object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)  and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154699/editing-a-primitives-values-after-initial-placement

Comment: Hello #batFinger, No my question has not been answered.  I do not know why it was closed.  I followed the link that said my question had been already answered; however, when I followed the steps the behavior was not as described.  Pressing F9 only brings up the last thing I did not the Math Function edit dialog.  This is very disappointing that I cannot find the correct answer and apparently am not allowed to ask.

Comment: Edit the question with details explaining why it is not a duplicate and it will be considered for re-opening. However even comment above is describing how blender works, you cannot go back and change operator properties once an object is created and you have used another operator. _ie_ if the F9 (Adjust Last Operation)  i  is not math Z surface then you will need to create another.  The dupe clearly states _"If you want to modify the last tool you have to do it before using another tool."_

Comment: Hello batFinger, If I create a Mesh using the Math Function and set it just the way I want then I duplicate the Mesh I am unable to change the Math Function parameters.  F9 will bring up the duplicate.  All that I am asking for is how do I bring up the Math Function Edit Dialog not the last tool that I used.  I do not know how to re-word it.

Comment: Yes as explained.  Dupe is another tool. After create one, Instead of duplicating run the math function again. Will have the previously used properties.