# How to re-open operator tab

Tags: properties

I just want to reopen with a hotkey, I alredy know that I can open it after we work with.

[image: Dialog]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created/165516#165516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-open it with F9. Although, the object operator settings menu cannot be accessed once you make an edit to the object.