# How do I show the left hand side bottom box

Tags: edit-mode

How do I show the left hand side bottom menu which is present right after Shift-A added object **Torus** once
I've closed it?
It should be labelled **Add Torus** in this case.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Comment: @RayMairlot Right!