# Increasing Amount of UV surfaces after sphere creation

Tags: subdivision-surface

In Blender 2.79 when you create a UV sphere the Add UV sphere menu pops up. As soon as you interact with the object in any way your ability to change the amount of segments and rings disappears.

My question: Is there a way to get this menu again or am I stuck with using a subdivision surface?
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you can't edit the primitive settings after you've altered it https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7851/86891

Comment: @Gorgious thanks for the answer, not what I hoped for, but tanks for letting me know.

Comment: @moonboots thanks for the answer, not what I hoped for, but tanks for letting me know.

Comment: What I am trying to do is not possible:
View " blender.stackexchange.com/a/7851/86891 " for reference. Props to Gorgious for providing the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit Parameters for an Object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)   Hi @The_Moth   Rather than answer confirming it as a duplicate,  closing as a duplicate is perhaps more apt.