# Automatic "Edit Window" popup - Blender 2.8

Tags: edit-mode

How to you make the window that pops up when you Move, Rotate, Resize, Extrude etc., to set specific options, popup automatically before making a change?

If I'm about to use proportional editing and I'm in move mode, and I need to change proportional size. I don't want to have to move the vertex first to make the window popup, then change the proportional size. I'd rather have all the options in front of me before doing anything.

[image]

Comment: You can change the proportional edit size by scrolling the mouse wheel, unless you need  very specific values.

Comment: U have the input scheme set to "industry standard" to fell like Unity/Maya. Unfortunately, the scroll functionality was lost after changing input style. I'm unsure what setting to change to enable it on that input scheme. That's why it would be great if the Move/Edit/Rotate etc window was always present, not just after changing a value.

Comment: The window is called the "Redo operator", and its purpose is to display the settings from the *last* operation you performed. It cannot, by definition, be displayed in a meaningful way before you've performed said operation as it would have to predict what tool you're going to use next.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit Parameters for an Object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the box reappear after it has dissappeared by pressing F9 key to change the settings. I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. Do you know what the actual setting name is called to make the window static?