# Add a new mesh object while also specifying its vertices count during creation (in 2.8 and later)--yet how to edit that same vertex count afterward?

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface

For example:

*Object Mode*!*Layout*!*Add*!*Mesh*!*Cylinder*.  Then, in lower left of the viewport, the dropdown *Add Cylinder*!*Vertices* is where you can change the number of vertices on the curve that comprises the cylinder before the creation of the cylinder is finalized.

But once the cylinder (or other curved object) is added, where is it possible to come back later and change its number of vertices?

Comment: The simple answer is: you  can't change the parameters on a primitive object after you've created it and did anything (on any object, no matter if it's the newly created or a different one) like moving, rotating, scaling or going into _Edit Mode_ etc. For more on this subject check this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Comment: It's a great answer.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: Having trouble figuring out where a "simple single vertex mesh" (suggested in one of the answers in the link) is being started from on Blender. In Add all I see are 3D meshes on the menu. Thanks again for any help with this.

Comment: Usually people in tutorials I've seen add a plane, go into _Edit Mode_, select all vertices and hit _M_ to merge them at center... that's how they get a single vertex mesh.