# How do you create a simple single vertex mesh with no actual faces whatsoever?

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface

In link [How to edit Parameters for an Object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created), it is suggested in one of the answers to begin a workaround by "Create(ing) a simple single vertex mesh with no actual faces whatsoever,...."

There's an animated GIF embedded within the answer that illustrates its making, but does not include the menus and commands involved.

All I see in my own 2.92 for Add is commands for meshes that are 3D objects, not anything like a simple vertex mesh.  Can anybody look at what's going on in the link and tell me how its author is building the first 8 seconds of the screen that is reproduced there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a cube or a plane or anything really, go into edit mode and select all with "a".  Then press "m" at center to merge all the vertices into one.

Alternatively enable the "mesh: extra objects" module in preferences and then you get an option to add a single vert.1

Specifically what this demo has done though is create a single vert as mentioned above, then duplicated it and moved the second one a little way off, then with both vertices selected they made an edge between them with "f".  Now you can hop into object mode and follow the rest of that little tutorial to make your cylinder.