# Annoying tool settings overlay

Tags: tools

I'm coming from ~18 years Maya usage and I'm relatively new to blender, so I'm heavely used to a construction history, which blender doesn't have.

My main problem is: everytime I add a new object e.g.: a Gear and want to adjust the parameters of the tool settings and then I just miss-click 1 pixel off an input field the tool settings confirms...
And I have to delete the object and start the add operation again.

Is there a way to make the tool settings overlay stop confirming when I accidently miss the input field?
Make it cursor-hit-test-able, have a confirm button, or even add construction history?

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are searching for might be <kbd>F9</kbd> which brings the [operator properties panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation) back (as long as you don't do anything else in between).

Also see: [How to edit Parameters for an Object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)

Comment: Thanks for this! It might not quite be the most comfortable solution for this problem, but it helps.

Comment: i know it's just a workaround. But better than "start from beginning again" ;)