# How should I get the “add” properties back after clicking?

Tags: mesh

Sorry if this is somewhat of a noob question, but I want to know if there is a way to get these properties (shown in picture) back after clicking somewhere and getting rid of them.  For further detail, they are the properties that show up immediately after adding a new mesh of some kind.  I occasionally accidentally click, and I hate when that happens, so I do want to know how to get these back without starting over on the mesh.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit Parameters for an Object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)

Answer (score 1):

Just press F9 to re-open that menu, if this is what you mean. (There is no image in your question)

[image]