# Add Mesh edit menu f9

Tags: interface

When you add a mesh like a sphere it comes with the "Mesh Edit Menu" in the corner. If you hit f9 it will bring it back. But f9 is only "last operation"
How can I find the menu below in blender?
[image: "Mesh Edit Menu"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit Parameters for an Object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the settings in the popup menu before you make any edits to the object.

The question was a little unclear. If that does not work, can you restate the question to make it a little bit more clear?