# Reversing an action: Bevelling

Tags: bevel

I'm learning Blender but something that strikes me as an infuriating oversight is the apparent lack of ability in the software to delete a feature like a Bevel. In Solidworks the features are listed and you can edit or delete them with a few clicks thm wheneber you like.

How do I delete a bevel. And don't say "undo". That's not useful at all. And how do I edit one after having made a few. If I want to come back to it and tweak it, how do I easily edit a bevel?

Surely there is a way to do such a simple task efficiently? Everyone is going on about how good blender is but there doesn't seem to be any way to do what should be an extremely simple and straightforward task.

Comment: Blender and Solidworks are 2 different softwares that don't have the same purpose, you can hardly compare. For the bevel, if you want to reverse you need to work with modifiers, don't bevel with Ctrl B, assign a Bevel modifier to your object and use the option that you need.

Comment: and this allows you to edit and delete it in future?

I'm aware that they are not comparable. But it doesn't excuse the lack of what should be a straightforward task from an UI perspective! But if this works then it answers the question and redeems blender for me haha!

Comment: Again, use the Bevel modifier, it is not destructive, but it may not always work, it really depends on your object. Also dig into the Geometry Node. The fact that they are 2 different softwares excuses the lack you're talking about, Solidworks is not capable of certain tasks as well. If you feel that you are able to fix this challenge in Blender I guess the Blender foundation would be glad to have you as a developer   ^^

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165516/19307

Comment: Thank you! Never wanted to compare to Solidworks though just to avoid confusion. I merely mentioned it to show that it's possible and from a sheer UI perspective it should be just as easy since it's a simple task.

Put it this way and answer the question: Should removing a bevel or editing it be a complicated task?

Comment: @MattBolt: sorry to say, but this sites is for solving specific problems you have with Blender. It is not about philisophic questions like "should it be a simple task". If you wanna discuss that, maybe search another forum/site like Blenderartists.org. And no, i didn't make the rules here...and moonboots already wrote: use a modifier, then it is an easy task to remove it (because it is a modifier).

Comment: and if you wanna use Blender a bit more professional, maybe think about the autosave option/add-on which saves a Blender file every x time so that you can go back to an earlier stage of your work.

Comment: Seems like we are getting very defensive about this :D. While this is a real problem in all surface modelling software. Solid modelling is simply way more suitable for easily adding bevels and it is going to be a more difficult task in any surface modelling software like Blender is. So the answer is - yes, it is a more complex task in Blender and it has to be, because of how surface modelling works with vertices, edges and faces. Bevel modifier however does make it non-destructive so some desired functionality will work(like being able to adjust and remove it later).

Answer (score 4):

Sure. There is a non-destructive way to make bevels - Bevel modifier.

[image]

You can choose a different limit method so you can define the edges that are beveled with it. You can do it by face angle, vertex group or weight. You can set weight of the bevel modifier for edges in edit mode:

[image]

Or assign vertices to vertex groups in the Mesh tab, in the Properties Editor:

[image]

Note that bevels are very different in surface modelling than in solid modelling and you will inevitably find that they are more limited in Blender(as well as in all other surface modelling software) than in something like Solidworks, because they need to work with the mesh consisting of vertices, edges and faces instead of some mathematical description of a volume. Bevel modifier will attempt to clamp the bevel if it results in overlapping geometry - this will often cause problems with complex or untidy topology that you will need to address(or consciously ignore sometimes).

[image]