Edit circle, change radius/diameter after creating
excuse my ignorance, but I've searched and I don't know how to do this:
-Change the diameter or radius of the circle, but after creating it, not before. When creating it, I get a window where I can place the measurement, but once created, I don't know how to modify it.
I have used other 3D modeling programs and I find it very easy to make parts like cups, cylinders, mechanical parts, gears. But with Blender it has been difficult for me, I have spent hours trying to see how to edit a circle. Or can they not be changed, can they only be scaled?

Hi. One way, in Object Mode, would be to change the dimensions in the Item tab of the N Panel. After doing that press Ctrl->A and click Scale to reset the scale to 1.0.

I suggest you to split this in two questions: the actual one related to parameter editing after object creation, and another different about CAD tools and addons. That way you can reach to more people and the solution to one question is not tied to the other.

Hello, motocross, welcome to BSE. Blender is not a CAD application, it's a 2&3D Visualization and Animation application, 3D largely  based on polygonal modelling, (not, for example, CSG.) Having said that, your complaint is not completely unreasonable, other VizAnim apps have parametric primitives. Blender is evolving towards a more procedural workflow, Geometry Nodes are a clear step in that direction... IMO, @LuisQuintana's suggestion is a good one. Perhaps ask a question about a specific, isolated, example of precision modelling, and ask us how we would do it in Blender.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165516/19307

If you press "N" you'll open a properties panel on your right. There, you will find the dimensions of the object you've selected. By default it's x:2m y:2m, you can edit these numbers to your specifications. When you're done you can press "N" again to close the panel.
